# Mysqli - Can i use '? = ?' in a prepare-Statement

Tags: php, mysqli

so im using MVC for DB connection ect.

My Question is pretty simple:
Is there a way for me to make my prepare dynamic, using something like ?=?.

Here is a example which doesn't seem to work:

```
$statement = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT fieldname FROM tablename WHERE ? = ?");
$statement->bind_param('ss', $stringvariable, $fieldvalue);
$statement->execute();
```

The example is in a function which receives the $stringvariable which contains a fieldname.

thanks for any suggestions on how to make something like this work!

EDIT!

It worked using a link posted by AlexK.

```
$statement = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT fieldname FROM tablename WHERE ".$stringvariable." = ?"); 
$statement->bind_param('s', $fieldvalue);
```

Comment: Well, I imagine this would "work", but might not do what you want it to do.  *Are* the values of `$stringvariable` and `$fieldvalue` equal?  Because that's what this is checking.  And then, if they are, this would return all records from the table.  Are you instead trying to parameterize a schema object name?

Comment: Only if they're both supposed to be string literals.... you can't bind table/column names

Comment: PS. MVC has absolutely nothing to do with prepared statements and variable bindings, that's purely a database thing

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! that actually helped. So I am now able to do it like this:

    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT fieldname FROM 
    tablename WHERE ".$stringvariable." = ?");
$statement->bind_param('ss', $fieldvalue);

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. Prepared statements are only useful for variables, and not for field names. You can however first add a check for the table name using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = ?;
```

If this results 1, you can safely add the table name as PHP variable inside the query to check the table name:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ? AND COLUMN_NAME = ?;
```

If this also results 1, you can safely add the table name and the column name in your query.

This method prevents from having SQL injection, by controlling the input first.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing it like this:

```
$statement = $this->dbh->prepare(
      sprintf("SELECT fieldname FROM tablename WHERE %s = ?;" ,$stringvariable)
);
$statement->bind_param('s', $fieldvalue);
$statement->execute();
```